# polyglossia list in one language followed by list in another language

Tags: lists, enumerate, polyglossia

I have a  mixed-language document.  It contains some `enumerate` lists written in English, and some numbered lists written in Arabic.  I am using polyglossia.

How can I fix this MWE?  The second list has no numbering, and only a ".".  The same problem applies to `itemize` lists (you get "." instead of a bullet-point).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item كلمه
\item كلمه
\end{enumerate}
\begin{english}
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is the first in the list
\item this is the second in the list
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can restore maghrib  form of numbers 1, 2, 3  instead of machriq ١،٢،٣  in case of default language set to arabic with `\let\@arabic\orig@arabic`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restarabic}{\let\@arabic\orig@arabic}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item كلمه
\item كلمه
\end{enumerate}
\begin{english}
\restarabic
\begin{enumerate}
\item this is the first in the list
\item this is the second in the list
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution works in this instance, but it permanently affects the document structures like `\section`.  My document uses a mashriq structure for TOC macro-structures like `chapter`s, `section`s, etc, but the micro-structures (like `enumerate` and `itemise`) are sometimes magrib and sometimes mashriq.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes just put `\restarabic` inside a group and the  command will be implemented only within this group, in the example above `\restarabic` will be executed only inside english environment.

Comment: I have just written a new question that may interest you, which asks about the next levels of nesting.