# mixed-language nested enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, polyglossia

In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266883/polyglossia-list-in-one-language-followed-by-list-in-another-language/266962?noredirect=1#comment641313_266962) I was given a simple way to switch temporarily to English `enumerate` whilst in a Arabic `mainlanguage` document.

This solution works for the *first* level of enumerate.  It doesn't work for the next levels in nested `enumerate` situations.

I am now asking how to do the next level — or even levels, if it is easy enough.

The MWE below includes the limited original solution and shows the problem clearly:

[image: Imgur]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% the next 3 lines are a solution from @selim-bou
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restarabic}{\let\@arabic\orig@arabic}
\makeatother

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{english}
This is going to be  a nested, numbered list.  The document is elsewhere mainly Arabic.
\begin{enumerate}
\restarabic
\item The first item
\item The second item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item A sub-item.
\item  Another sub-item  
\end{enumerate}
\item A third, main item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `\let\@alph\@origalph` to restore alphabetic format a,b,c in the second level of enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\restcount}{
\let\@arabic\orig@arabic%
\let\@alph\@origalph%
\let\@Alph\@origAlph%
}
\makeatother

\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{english}
This is going to be  a nested, numbered list.  The document is elsewhere mainly Arabic.
\begin{enumerate}
\restcount
\item The first item
\item The second item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item A sub-item.
\item  Another sub-item  
\end{enumerate}
\item A third, main item.
\end{enumerate}
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Comment: would you do another one by babel, please